# openGL figure not staying together when moved

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I'm drawing a stick figure in OpenGL and I have the body (which I'm using `GL_LINES` for) and the head (which I'm using `GL_LINE_LOOP` for).  After drawing these out, they all show up perfectly fine.  However, when I go to move the stick figure all over the screen, the head disconnects from the body.  I need these to stay as one for game purposes.  Can anyone help me out and explain it as well?

If you need me to explain further as well, just let me know.

```
//Drawing body
glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glColor3f(1,1,1);
    glVertex2f(xpos, ypos);
    glVertex2f(xpos - xdim/2, ypos - ydim);             
    glVertex2f(xpos, ypos);
    glVertex2f(xpos + xdim/2, ypos - ydim);             
    glVertex2f(xpos, ypos);
    glVertex2f(xpos, ypos + ydim);                  
    glVertex2f(xpos - xdim/2, ypos + ydim/2);
    glVertex2f(xpos, ypos + ydim);                  
    glVertex2f(xpos - xdim/2, ypos + ydim/2);       
    glVertex2f(xpos - xdim/4, ypos + ydim/2);           
    glVertex2f(xpos - xdim/4, ypos + ydim/2);   
    glVertex2f(xpos - xdim/4, ypos + ydim/3);   
    glVertex2f(xpos - xdim/4, ypos + ydim/2);
    glVertex2f(xpos + xdim, ypos + ydim/2);         
    glVertex2f(xpos + xdim, ypos + ydim/2);
    glVertex2f(xpos + xdim, ypos + ydim/3);         
    glVertex2f(xpos + xdim, ypos + ydim/2);
    glVertex2f(xpos + xdim + xdim/2, ypos + ydim/2);  
    glVertex2f(xpos + xdim/2, ypos + ydim/2);
    glVertex2f(xpos, ypos + ydim);                      
    glVertex2f(xpos, ypos + ydim + ydim/4);
    glVertex2f(xpos, ypos + ydim);                      
glEnd();

//Drawing head
glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP); 
    glColor3f(1,1,1);
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        j = 2*3.14*i/100;
        glVertex2f(200 + 15 * cos(j), 254 + 15 * sin(j));
    }
glEnd();
```

Comment: We need to see how you move your body parts. You probably have duplicate move due to OpenGL being a state machine.

Comment: To go along with @KromStern, are you using your `glPush()` and `glPop()`s correctly? This is assuming that you are using OpenGL immediate mode, if you aren't, then the problem is how you are utilizing your own matrices.

Comment: Would it help if I put up the draw portion of my stick figure up here?

Comment: Assuming that you move the character with `xpos` and `ypos`, you need to add those to the head's vertices in the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's quite obvious: You need to apply same transforms to all of your figure parts in order keep them together.

Depending on the figure hierarchy:

- if it is individual parts: add the same offset to each part. Watch to avoid matrix stack changes in between (in FFP glPush/glPop);
- if you use a list/tree-like parts hierarchy - make sure parts are parented properly and you apply transform only once to the root.

---

In your code sample: You seem to use `xpos` / `ypos` to move the body, but you don't add them to the head - hence it's not moving along.